# django-cities-light ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django, package

I am getting error when I run python manage.py cities_light

here is the complete error

```
Assuming local download is up to date for http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cities_light/management/commands/cities_light.py", line 215, in handle
    self.country_import(items)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cities_light/management/commands/cities_light.py", line 308, in country_import
    country = Country.objects.get(geoname_id=items[ICountry.geonameid])
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1315, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/khalid/Desktop/file whersk/wherks-web/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to [this](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/issues/254).
This problem has been considered and is still open, but there is already a solution.

> pip install git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light.git@master

This should help.